# how to make acts_as_list behave with groupings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a small rails app that is using acts_as_list to implement drag and drop via ajax.

The app has 3 main models: forms, sections, and questions.  As it is designed, forms have many sections, and sections have many questions.

I want a user to be able to do 3 things:

1. reorder the sections in forms
2. reorder the questions in the sections
3. dnd a question into a different section as well.

I have a setup that can handle #1 and #2, but I am having problems with #3.

You'll find the view snippet below.  Any ideas on where to start with #3?

```
<p>
<ul id="section-list" style="cursor: move">
  <% @form.sections.each do |s| %>
    <li id="section_<%= s.id %>">
      <%= s.name %>
            <ul id="question-list-<%= s.id %>" style="cursor: move">
              <% s.questions.each do |q| %>
                    <li id="question_<%= q.id %>"><%= q.content %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`acts_as_list` takes a `:scope` option.

```
acts_as_list :scope => "section_id"
```